# Why would $PATH be getting overwritten after shell login?

Tags: macos, bash, path, homebrew, zsh

It seems like there are a hundred questions on here about how to change your path in Mac OS X/Linux environments....thing is I thought  actually knew how to change my PATH variable but it seems like something is causing it to get overwritten.  I'm using zsh and trying to get `Brew Doctor` to not warn me about having usr/bin before user/local/bin. 
My ~/.zprofile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
echo $PATH
```

And on login I get:

```
Last login: Fri Oct 17 15:10:30 on ttys000
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But upon running $PATH after login I get:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I'm logging directly in to zsh but just in case my .profile and .bash-profile both contain the same code as my .zprofile and there is nothing in my /etc/paths.d directory. Is there some other place the PATH is set? What am I missing here?

Comment: Exporting an environment variable only effects child processes of the process in which you exported. A new login (terminal I assume) is not a child process of the shell in which you just set that path, thus the PATH is not set.

Comment: Normally, you don't completely reset the value of `PATH` in your personal files; you just add directories to the value inherited from the system configuration.

Comment: @jrwren Setting the value of the variable affects the current shell; `export` just exports a name so the child environments inherit the value; it does not push a value into the environment.

Comment: @chepner that is what i said :)

Comment: The implication was that the change in the value of `PATH` made at the time it was exported only applies to the child process. That's incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your .zprofile is read, zsh will read .zshrc and .zlogin (assuming a login shell). Your PATH could be getting reset in either of those.

In general, PATH is best set in .zshenv (which will be read even if the shell isn’t a login shell). Then don’t set it in any of the other startup files.

Comment: AHA! Thank you very much! I had read somewhere that .zshrc only gets used if you're using the shell in interactive mode (ie not as your login shell). Found export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin about halfway down. Fixed that and it worked!

Comment: Took your tip about .zshenv and that worked with login and non-login. Brilliant advice!

Comment: `~/.zshenv` is supposed to be the ideal place to set the PATH. However on OS X and Arch (and previously Gentoo), the system `/etc/zprofile` which is executed _after_ `~/.zshenv` will overwrite the `PATH` variable - so to workaround that issue, `PATH` and `MANPATH` settings should be placed in one of the later files such `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, and `~/.zlogin`.

Comment: Thanks, @pyrachi , I was pulling my hair out!

Comment: Pam environment common to all choices of shell. I think. Its damn confusing and varies distro to distro. But env files are the way to go. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Answer (score 8):

From:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh

> Users should take note that /etc/profile sets the $PATH variable which will
>       overwrite any $PATH variable set in ~/.zshenv. To prevent this, please set
>       the $PATH variable in ~/.zshrc. (It's not recommended to replace the default
>       one line in /etc/zsh/zprofile with something other, it'll break the integrity
>       of other packages which provide some scripts in /etc/profile.d)

From:
http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

```
For zsh: [Note that zsh seems to read ~/.profile as well, if ~/.zshrc is not present.]

+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|                |Interactive|Interactive|Script|
|                |login      |non-login  |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|/etc/zshenv     |    A      |    A      |  A   |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|~/.zshenv       |    B      |    B      |  B   |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|/etc/zprofile   |    C      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|~/.zprofile     |    D      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|/etc/zshrc      |    E      |    C      |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|~/.zshrc        |    F      |    D      |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|/etc/zlogin     |    G      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|~/.zlogin       |    H      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|                |           |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|                |           |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|~/.zlogout      |    I      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
|/etc/zlogout    |    J      |           |      |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------+

Moral:
For bash, put stuff in ~/.bashrc, and make ~/.bash_profile source it.
For zsh, put stuff in ~/.zshrc, which is always executed.
```

Comment: Zshrc about the worst place as its sourced repeatedly in my experience...  On debian it was anyway. Ditto für bash. Way better to use the env files or pam. /etc/zsh/zshenv setting the base path a good hint. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Jet Brains product (pycharm/goland/webstorm etc) you may find that the JB shell integration on their terminal is overwriting the `$PATH`. You can disable it by unticking
Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell integration. 
[image: disable shell integration]
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html for more info.